# Python multiprocessing creates incorrect pids

Tags: python, multiprocessing, rpy2

I've been working on this for some time now, but can't seem to figure it out.  I have it narrowed down to situations where my code and the os (Python 2.7.3 on linux) don't agree on which processes should be running.  When this happens, my code hangs forever, but there are no exceptions thrown.  Sometimes the code will run properly for hours, sometimes only for a few minutes, and I can't figure out why.  This is manifested as below.  Thanks for having a look, I'm really in a pickle (pun-intended) here.

code output:

Creating discrete character matrix

```
running PoolWorker_82 (72 triplets), pid 25777, ppid 24892
running PoolWorker_83 (72 triplets), pid 25778, ppid 24892
running PoolWorker_84 (72 triplets), pid 25779, ppid 24892
running PoolWorker_85 (72 triplets), pid 25780, ppid 24892
running PoolWorker_86 (72 triplets), pid 25781, ppid 24892
running PoolWorker_87 (72 triplets), pid 25782, ppid 24892
running PoolWorker_88 (72 triplets), pid 25783, ppid 24892
running PoolWorker_89 (90 triplets), pid 25784, ppid 24892
```

output from ps aux...

```
1000     24892  2.0  0.9 559948 151088 pts/0   Sl+  09:14   0:16 p runsimulation.py
1000     25776  0.0  0.8 559932 138320 pts/0   S+   09:19   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26015  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26021  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26023  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26025  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26027  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26029  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26031  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
1000     26036  0.0  0.8 559948 138140 pts/0   S+   09:22   0:00 p runsimulation.py
```

You can see that the parent process 24982 is there, but the pids of the workers are not.  Normally, these will match, I can see the worker CPU usage go to 100% while they are working, and then they all go away after the iteration is done.  When it fails, I get the pid mismatch and processes which are using 0.0% CPU (column 3).

The relevant portions of my code are below (in reverse order in which they are called):

R setup with functions that are called with rpy2:

```
def create_R(dir):
    """
    creates the r environment
    @param dir: the directory for the output files
    """
    r = robjects.r
    importr("phangorn")
    importr("picante")
    importr("MASS")
    importr("vegan")
    r("options(expressions=500000)")
    robjects.globalenv['outfile'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir, "trees.pdf"))
    r('pdf(file=outfile, onefile=T)')
    r("par(mfrow=c(2,3))")

    r("""
        generate_triplet = function(bits) {
        triplet = replicate(bits, rTraitDisc(tree, model="ER", k=2,states=0:1))
        triplet = t(apply(triplet, 1, as.numeric))
        sums = rowSums(triplet)
        if (length(which(sums==0)) > 0 && length(which(sums==3)) == 1) {
            return(triplet)
        }
        return(generate_triplet(bits))
        }
    """)

    r("""
        get_valid_triplets = function(numsamples, needed, bits) {
            tryCatch({
                m = generate_triplet(bits)
                while (ncol(m) < needed) {
                    m = cbind(m, generate_triplet(bits))
                }
            return(m)
            }, error = function(e){print(message(e))}, warning = function(e){print(message(e))})
        }
    """)
```

The function called within the workers:

```
def __get_valid_triplets(num_samples, num_triplets, bits, q):
    r = robjects.r
    name = current_process().name.replace("-", "_")
    timer = stopwatch.Timer()
    log("\trunning %s (%d triplets), pid %d, ppid %d" % (name, num_triplets, current_process().pid, os.getppid()),
        log_file)
    r('%s = get_valid_triplets(%d, %d, %d)' % (name, num_samples, num_triplets, bits))
    q.put((name, r[name]))
    timer.stop()
    log("\t%s complete (%s)" % (name, str(timer)), log_file)
```

The function which sets up the pool, and dispatches workers using apply_async.  The wokers write to a managed queue which is processes after the pool has joined:

```
def __generate_candidate_discrete_matrix(num_cols, num_samples, sample_tree, bits, usable_cols):
    assert isinstance(sample_tree, dendropy.Tree)
    print "Creating discrete character matrix"
    r = robjects.r
    newick = sample_tree.as_newick_string()
    num_samples = len(sample_tree.leaf_nodes())
    robjects.globalenv['numcols'] = usable_cols
    robjects.globalenv['newick'] = newick + ";"
    r("tree = read.tree(text=newick)")
    r('m = matrix(nrow=length(tree$tip.label))') #create empty matrix
    r('m = m[,-1]') #drop the first NA column
    num_procs = mp.cpu_count()
    args = []
    div, mod = divmod(usable_cols, num_procs)
    [args.append(div) for i in range(num_procs)]
    args[-1] += mod
    for i, elem in enumerate(args):
        div, mod = divmod(elem, bits)
        args[-1] += mod
        args[i] -= mod
    manager = Manager()
    pool = Pool(processes=num_procs, maxtasksperchild=1)
    q = manager.Queue(maxsize=num_procs)
    for arg in args:
        pool.apply_async(__get_valid_triplets, (num_samples, arg, bits, q))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    while not q.empty():
        name, data = q.get()
        robjects.globalenv[name] = data
        r('m = cbind(m, %s)' % name)

    r('m = m[,1:%d]' % usable_cols)
    r('m = m[order(rownames(m)),]') # consistently order the rows 
    r('m = t(apply(m, 1, as.numeric))') # convert all factors given by rTraitDisc to numeric
    a = r['m']
    n = r('rownames(m)')
    return a, n
```

Finally, the first function called which generates the candidate matrix, makes sure it's a valid one, and if not it will try again with a new matrix.  If it is valid, it stores some things in R session and returns the data

```
def create_discrete_matrix(num_cols, num_samples, sample_tree, bits):
    """
    Creates a discrete char matrix from a tree
    @param num_cols: number of columns to create
    @param sample_tree: the tree
    @return: a r object of the matrix, and a list of the row names
    @rtype: tuple(robjects.Matrix, list)
    """
    r = robjects.r
    usable_cols = find_usable_length(num_cols, bits)
    a, n = __generate_candidate_discrete_matrix(num_cols, num_samples, sample_tree, bits, usable_cols)
    assert isinstance(a, robjects.Matrix)
    assert a.ncol == usable_cols

    paralin_matrix, valid = __create_paralin_matrix(a)
    if valid is False:
        sample_tree = create_tree(num_samples, type = "S")
        return create_discrete_matrix(num_cols, num_samples, sample_tree, bits)
    else:
        robjects.globalenv['paralin_matrix'] = paralin_matrix
        r('rownames(paralin_matrix) = rownames(m)')
        r('paralin_dist = as.dist(paralin_matrix, diag=T, upper=T)')
        r("paralinear_cluster = hclust(paralin_dist, method='average')")
    return sample_tree, a, n
```

Comment: Well, you most likely hit a bug in python multiprocessing here. Try to further narrow the code that generates the error ou are getting, and open a bug on Python bug tracker at bugs.python.org

Comment: Thanks, jsbueno.  Already done!  The bug report is here: http://bugs.python.org/issue15603.  The bug must be happening somewhere in the worker, but all efforts to track it down have failed.  I tend to only post on here when I'm at the end of my rope, right before I toss my laptop out the window.

Comment: Is this really the smallest example to reproduce the problem ? Did you start by say, have the workers do nothing but import rpy2 and see if the problem is already there ?

Comment: It definitely is NOT the smallest example of the problem.  Once I took a step back and wrote one, I accidentally made a mistake in a print statement in the worker.  When there was no traceback sent, like there should have been, I realized that there would be no way for it to propagate back to the main thread (where there was a try).  So, in my code, I added explicitly a try/except in __get_valid_triplets which would function in each worker process in the pool.  Fingers crossed, waiting for a traceback now...

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was fixed by a server reboot (FML).  However, valid information was gained.  When submitting workers to a pool, make sure to trap exceptions in the worker itself, rather than trapping them in the method that calls pool.apply_async.

```
def __get_valid_triplets(num_samples, num_triplets, bits, q):
    try:
        r = robjects.r
        name = current_process().name.replace("-", "_")
        timer = stopwatch.Timer()
        log("\trunning %s (%d triplets), pid %d, ppid %d" % (name, num_triplets, current_process().pid, os.getppid()),
            log_file)
        r('%s = get_valid_triplets(%d, %d, %d)' % (name, num_samples, num_triplets, bits))
        q.put((name, r[name]))
        timer.stop()
        log("\t%s complete (%s)" % (name, str(timer)), log_file)
    except Exception, e:
        q.put("DEATH")
        traceback.print_exc()
```